# Twilio flow events with event streams

Tags: twilio

I am trying to learn the Twilio API with a simple Twilio Studio script that places a call to a number, and if it is answered connects to another number. The Studio flow is driven by a python script, and if the number is not connected, it waits N minutes and kicks off the flow again. I'd like to log the final state of each call attempt (e.g., "busy").

I am trying to do the logging with event streams. Following the webhook quickstart at https://www.twilio.com/docs/events/webhook-quickstart, I installed the Twilio CLI, logged in, created the webhook sink with my flow's webhook URL, and then created a subscription for com.twilio.studio.flow.execution.started, com.twilio.studio.flow.execution.ended and
com.twilio.studio.flow.step.ended. But .... I don't see any events, or any obvious (to me) CLI option to view them. If I list the sinks, it says the webhooks are active. I'm missing something big here ... but I don't know what it is?

Eternal gratitude to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Have you built an application to receive the webhook events? [This blog post is a good overview of setting all this up](https://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-studio-event-streams).

Comment: This was *exactly* the pointer I needed, thanks!! The piece I was missing was making the sink URL publicly accessible. And I'd never heard of the ngrok reverse proxy service before, but it worked wonderfully here. Eternal gratitude rightatcha. :)